# When joining parts together, the skin modifier disappears. How is this resolved?

Tags: modeling

A student of mine is having an issue with the baby dragon he is sculpting. When he attempts to join the body parts together, the skin modifier disappears. I have included an after shot as well as the blend file. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the link to the file: [image] [image]

Comment: I could not load the blend file at this time. Anyone reviewing this question, please message me for the blend file. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, you can upload blend files to [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) and add the provided link as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Thank you, @Timaroberts

Comment: When joining objects, modiifers of the active object (if any) will be ones the resulting object will take. If there are none, joined result won't have any modifiers (nor any of their effects obviously).

Comment: Thank you @MrZak for your help.